# Unexpected assert failure error

Tags: c++, sorting, opengl

I can not find a better title for this question because, to be honest, I have no idea why I´m getting this error.
The code is:

```
std::sort(VisibleMeshes.begin(), VisibleMeshes.end(), [](const MeshBase* m1, const MeshBase* m2) -> bool
{
    float d1 = CamerasManager::ActiveCamera->Position.Distance(m1->MeshPosition);
    float d2 = CamerasManager::ActiveCamera->Position.Distance(m2->MeshPosition);

    return d1 > d2;
});
```

VisibleMeshes is a vector of MeshBase objects (pointers).
The purpose is to sort this objects by the distance from the camera, from the farthest to the nearest.
The code works almost always but, from time to time, I get an assert failure.
The error is

```
"invalid operator <"
```

Any ideas?

This is the full error I get:
[image]

Comment: Where does the assert come from? Have you ran it in GDB to get a backtrae? What is the exact error message?

Comment: You have, probably, corrupted the memory. Check recent code changes.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I edited the question with a screenshot of the full erro message

Comment: You normally get this assertion if your comparison function is found to not define a strict weak ordering, for example `[](int, int) { return rand() % 2 == 0; }`.

Comment: Can assert failure be expected?

Answer (score 0):

I´ll answer myself because I found the issue and the solution could help someone else.
I´m building a rendering engine and I´m using two threads to draw the scene and update it. The draw loop runs at 60 fps while the update loop runs at 500 fps.
The camera position is updated in the update loop (faster) and this sorting happens in the draw loop. Being the update loop much faster, sometimes (rarely) happens that the camera position changes in the middle of the vectort sort. This code fixes th issue

```
Vector3 CameraPosition(CamerasManager::ActiveCamera->Position); // Copy current camera position

std::sort(VisibleMeshes.begin(), VisibleMeshes.end(), [&](const MeshBase* m1, const MeshBase* m2) -> bool
    {
        float d1 = CameraPosition.Distance(m1->MeshPosition);
        float d2 = CameraPosition.Distance(m2->MeshPosition);

        return d1 > d2;
    }
);
```

Basically I´m capturing a copy of the camera position into the lambda to be sure it does not change during the sort

Comment: What happens if the list is modified while you're copying it? Sounds like your doing synchronization-less threading, which is a bad idea.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes it is, but in this case is safe. The list of visible meshes (they are grass clusters) is updated right before the sorting and in the same thread